# how to select multiple multiline groups in regex

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following text:

```
ajhsdkjad lkajsdkl a
 sadkjalksd  a lkjdsadk a
//#IF HI
//#as sjhdjakdj  jlkajs kja
#sa ajkdslkaj dlkasd kasdklj
//#ENDIF
a djalk jskdj kls jdklsjd
//#IF HI 
a sjkalj dklajskl klsjd s
//#ENDIF
a sjkldajdlkasksss
```

And want to get the following groups:

```
1)
    //#IF HI
    //#as sjhdjakdj  jlkajs kja
    #sa ajkdslkaj dlkasd kasdklj
    //#ENDIF
2)
    //#IF HI 
    a sjkalj dklajskl klsjd s
    //#ENDIF
```

and replace them adding a // at the beginning, resulting in a string such as:

```
ajhsdkjad lkajsdkl a
 sadkjalksd  a lkjdsadk a
////#IF HI
////#as sjhdjakdj  jlkajs kja
//#sa ajkdslkaj dlkasd kasdklj
////#ENDIF
a djalk jskdj kls jdklsjd
////#IF HI 
//a sjkalj dklajskl klsjd s
////#ENDIF
a sjkldajdlkasksss
```

I tried the following regex: //#if HI(\n|.)*//#endif
but this selects everything as whole in one group.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

If this looks strange, please note that the OP made a huge change to the request in mid-flight, after lots of work. Originally the lines did not start with `//`, and had to receive an `//`. Now they already start with `//`. The answers to the new reqs are under C and D at the bottom.

**A. Matching the Groups**

You can use this simple regex (see [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uQ4nD8)) to match the whole groups in one block:

```
(?s)#IF.*?#ENDIF
```

In Groovy:

```
Matcher regexMatcher = subjectString =~ /(?s)#IF.*?#ENDIF/
if (regexMatcher.find()) {
    String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
}
```

**Explain Regex**

```
(?s)                     # set flags for this block (with . matching
                         # \n) (case-sensitive) (with ^ and $
                         # matching normally) (matching whitespace
                         # and # normally)
#IF                      # '#IF'
.*?                      # any character (0 or more times (matching
                         # the least amount possible))
#ENDIF                   # '#ENDIF'
```

**B. Inserting `//` at the start of each line**

Here we need a different approach, because we need to target the input line by line.

You can use this (see the Substitutions at the bottom of the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/yS4lS3)):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(/(?m)(#(?:END)?IF[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*|\G(?=(?:[^#]|#(?!IF))*#ENDIF)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*)/, '//$1');
```

For this one, please note the regex explanations in the top right pane of the demo.

**C. New Requirements: matching from `//#IF` to `//#ENDIF`**

Use something like this:

```
def matchList = [];
Matcher regexMatcher = subjectString =~ '(?s)//#IF.*?//#ENDIF'
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

**D. New Requirements: replacements when lines already start with `//`**

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(/(?m)(\/\/#(?:END)?IF[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*|\G(?=(?:[^#]|#(?!IF))*#ENDIF)[^\r\n]*[\r\n]*)/, '//$1');
```

Comment: ah, i was missing the ? for the least amount possible. Do you know how could I add the // at the beginning of each line in the groups?

Comment: If I add an extra # in the beginning of a line inside an #IF and #ENDIF, it won't capture the content within. Also I meant to use //#IF and //#ENDIF instead of #IF and #ENDIF, can you make those changes please. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the upvoting button I've only used the check before.

Comment: @luis I took care of the first one (the `#` in the middle). I don't understand the second one. What are we looking for, and what are we replacing it with?

Comment: I just made a change. to illustrate the case I was talking about

Comment: By the example, I am meaning that I want to basically select anything or any type of characters within the //#IF and //#ENDIF.

Comment: @luis I made the adjustments, look at parts C and D of the answer.

Comment: Thanks, bro! It took some time but we got there. Sorry about the short temper. :)